# SharePoint Online Document Set Limit

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Is there a limit to the number of document sets you can create in one document library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of document sets you can create in a document library.
Please use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/document-set-planning#administering-document-sets) as a reference

Answer (score 2):

A list can have up to 30 million items and a library can have up to 30 million files and folders. Views can have up to 12 lookup columns.

Reference [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498).

Looks like a big library however there is a downside of this, Even though you have lets say 20000 files. The list will only show up to 5000 files in a list. Usually the latest 5000 files.

Reference [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59).

There is a way to increase the threshold, you can check [here](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-overcome-sharepoint-5000-item-limit-threshold/).

----------**Updates**----------

As [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-document-sets-3dbcd93e-0bed-46b7-b1ba-b31de2bcd234) mentioned, document set is group of related documents as a single entity. which in theory it should share the file limits with a regular files limits. Also, from the first reference, File size - Less than 15 GB per file. Files attached to list items can be up to 250 MB in size. which should apply to document sets as well.

Comment: I've come across the link you referenced, but I'm not sure a document set counts as a list item. I've done a lot of on-prem server-side code creating and manipulating document sets, and it's completely different to regular list items.

Comment: I'm not worried about the list view threshold. We're using a custom search solution to manage the documents

Comment: @Appelman as [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-3DBCD93E-0BED-46B7-B1BA-B31DE2BCD234) mentioned, document set is group of related docuemts as a single entity.  which in theory it should share the file limits with a regular files limits.  Also, from the first reference, File size - Less than 15 GB per file. Files attached to list items can be up to 250 MB in size. which should apply to document sets as well.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense